# Driver Testing an error occurred deploying the driver(s) in the solution : The system can not find the file specified

Tags: windows, visual-studio, wdm

I am trying to create a very simple WDM driver in Visual Studio 2013.
I have successfully provisioned a virtual pc running win7 sp1 x86 on a wmware machine using serial port.
Now that i want to debug the driver, i get the error :

> Driver Testing an error occurred deploying the driver(s) in the solution : The system can not find the file specified.

What is the cause here and how can i solve this problem?

[image: Here is the snapshot showing the error along with the driver code itself]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select MyDriver1 Package as a startup project.